Summary statistics in data.table using quantile and other statistics
I am attempting to summarize data using data.table in R. The problem is that within my summarization framework the use of quantile spits out the results in rows instead of columns. I have a simple enough workaround, but I wanted to see if there is a more direct way to get the output I want.
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

#create some example data
dt<-data.table(ID=rep(1:3, each=100),
              val=rnorm(300,100, sd=20))

#define percentiles of interest
percs=c(0.05, 0.10, 0.50, 0.75, 0.90, 0.95)

The following code provides all of the data I want, but not in the format I want. It puts each percentile on a new row and then replicates the previous summary statistics (mean, median, max min). I want each percentile in a new column.
#Summarize the data - this is the brevity I want but the format puts the percentiles in new rows
dt[,.(mean=mean(val, na.rm=T),
      Median=median(val, na.rm=T),
      min=min(val, na.rm=T),
      max=max(val, na.rm=T),
      as.list(quantile(val, probs=percs, na.rm=T))),
   by=ID]

The following code gives me the format I want, but now I am doing two operations and gluing the results together. Ultimately this is fine, but I would rather a code structure like the previous snippet with output formatted as below.
#summarize data - this is the format I want it in but don't want the extra operations
dt[,.(mean=mean(val, na.rm=T),
      Median=median(val, na.rm=T),
      min=min(val, na.rm=T),
      max=max(val, na.rm=T)),
    by=ID]%>%
cbind(.,dt[,setDT(as.list(quantile(val, probs=percs, na.rm=T))),by=ID][,-1]) #-1 to remove extraneous ID column


Adjust the list/. and c() it together:
dt[, c(.(mean=mean(val, na.rm=T),
      Median=median(val, na.rm=T),
      min=min(val, na.rm=T),
      max=max(val, na.rm=T)),
      as.list(quantile(val, probs=percs, na.rm=T))),
   by=ID]

##      ID     mean    Median      min      max       5%      10%       50%      75%      90%      95%
##   <int>    <num>     <num>    <num>    <num>    <num>    <num>     <num>    <num>    <num>    <num>
##1:     1 98.10946 100.26609 48.79013 146.2197 63.89160 74.69887 100.26609 111.0710 120.4167 123.0090
##2:     2 99.60213  97.59593 43.34578 154.0955 70.26721 78.71858  97.59593 113.1770 122.5518 129.5174
##3:     3 99.77979 101.09318 51.12685 154.8843 69.68815 77.37456 101.09318 109.0072 123.1126 129.3033


A very slight refinement:
g <- function(x, probs=(1:3)/4, qnames=c(‘Q1’, ‘Median’, ‘Q2’)) {
  x <- x[! is.na(x)]
  qu <- quantile(x, probs=probs)
  names(qu) <- qnames
  r <- range(x)
  # data.table requires consistent numeric mode, hence as.double
  as.list(as.double(c(Min=r[1], Max=r[2], Mean=mean(x)), qu)))
}

dt[, g(val), by=ID]

Writing little functions makes it easy to debug calculations for one subject.  Then you let data.table repeat for all subjects.
